# why event system markup is needed while functions can be passed as props

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Vue has special template markup for event handling

```html
<template>
<button type="button" @click="onClickFunction">
click me
</button>
</template>
```

but I have no idea why this event handling markup is needed since functions can be passed as props, the code above can change to

```html
<template>
<button type="button" :onClick="onClickFunction">
click
</button>
</template>
```

Using `v-bind` syntax for event handling can save a lot docs, isn't it?
And making the template less DSL-ish, much easier to learn.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html